# Android Gradle Build Target got Error

Tags: android, android-studio

While running project i got following error message.I cant understand whats going on please help me.
[image: Error:Android Gradle Build Target: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger]

How it resolve?

Comment: Am getting the same issue compiling a java module not an Android project, i've been using a java module for green-dao api and it was working fine , this issue happened in android studio 2.2 preview 7
would you edit your question to give more information?

Comment: This still happens in preview android studios (2.4 currently). Works normally when opened in stable 2.3.